# Get rowSpec and columnSpec from Button in GridLayout

Tags: android, grid-layout, layoutparams

I have a gridlayout containing buttons. If I touch one button I want to know which button it was. Therefore I need the span of the rowSpec and columnSpec.

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = clickedbutton.getLayoutParams();
String rowSpec = layoutParams.rowSpec.span;
```

This doesn't work because it doesn't know rowSpec (which should work in my understanding)
While debugging I can see that the layoutParams contains the needed value. I just can't find a way to access them.

Comment: :Why do you wnt span you just get the position of button and identify which button is clicked.

Comment: well i have 576 buttons which are in this grid. is there another way to get the clicked button?

Comment: Its better to play with item position so their is no conflict while accessing.